# want to layer aes in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, layer

I would like to plot another series of data on top of a current graph. The additional data only contains information for 3 (out of 6) spp, which are used in the facet_wraping.

The other series of data is currently a column (in the same data file).

Current graph:

```
ped.num <- ggplot(data, aes(ped.length, seeds.inflorstem))

ped.num + geom_point(size=2) + theme_bw() + facet_wrap(~spp, scales = "free_y")
```

Additional layer would be:

```
aes(ped.length, seeds.filled)
```

I feel I should be able to plot them using the same y-axis, because they have just slightly smaller values. How do I go about add this layer?

Comment: Did you try adding `+ geom_point(aes(ped.length, seeds.filled))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ialm 's solution should work fine, but I recommend calling the `aes` function separately in each `geom_*` because it makes the code easier to read.

```
ped.num <- ggplot(data) +
                 geom_point(aes(x=ped.length, y=seeds.inflorstem), size=2) +
                 theme_bw() + 
                 facet_wrap(~spp, scales="free_y") +
                 geom_point(aes(x=ped.length, y=seeds.filled))
```

Answer (score 2):

(You'll always get better answers if you include example data, but I'll take a shot in the dark)

Since you want to plot two variables that are on the same `data.frame`, it's probably easiest to reshape the data before feeding it into ggplot:

```
library(reshape2)

# Melting data gives you exactly one observation per row - ggplot likes that
dat.melt <- melt(dat, 
                 id.var = c("spp", "ped.length"),
                 measure.var = c("seeds.inflorstem", "seeds.filled")
)


# Plotting is slightly different - instead of explicitly naming each variable,
# you'll refer to "variable" and "value"
ggplot(dat.melt, aes(x = ped.length, y = value, color = variable)) +
    geom_point(size=2) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    facet_wrap(~spp, scales = "free_y")
```

The `seeds.filled` values should plot only on the facets for the corresponding species.

I prefer this to Drew's (totally valid) approach of explicitly mapping different layers because you only need a single `geom_point()` whether you have two variables or twenty and it's easy to map a variety of aesthetics to `variable`.